# In python, how could I make this three line code into a one line code?

Tags: python, copy

Here's the code

```
from sys import argv
script,from_file, to_file = argv
open(to_file,'w').write(open(from_file).read())
```

I'm new to python, and I'm [Learning Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/index), on the extra credit for one problem, it says the writer of the book was able to make the code one line long, so I managed to get it down to 3 lines, but I'm stuck.

Care to help?

Oh, and the code copies the contents of one file to another, or it is meant to.  That's my goal.

Comment: "Learning Bad Python the Stupid Way" would be a better title for something that encourages spending time learning to force code to fit on one line.

Comment: "Care to help?".  No.  Code Golf is a bad thing.  Stop now.

Comment: Your code is very clean!  See also shutil and argparse modules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to do this as one *expression* i.e. without needing semicolons:

```
__import__('shutil').copy(__import__('sys').argv[1], __import__('sys').argv[2])
```

or

```
open(__import__('sys').argv[2], "w").write(open(__import__('sys').argv[1]).read())
```

---

Of course, nobody in their right mind would prefer this to your sample code. The only change I would make is that there's no reason to assign the file names to temporary variables:

```
from sys import argv
open(argv[1],'w').write(open(argv[2]).read())
```

A more Pythonic way of writing this would be:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as src, open(sys.argv[2]) as dest:
    for line in src:
        dest.write(line)
```

and then you could start using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) to make the command-line reading more robust...

Comment: +1 this is the way to do that in one line, if you want to...and, of course, nobody should use it ;)

Comment: Thanks! I think the intention of getting me to write it in one line is to learn about referencing those arg values directly, as I didn't know how to do that before.  I think two lines is good enough, the programmer can keep his ugly one-liner.

Answer (score 6):

You can use semicolon to keep the import statement on the same line. And reference the items in argv directly instead of using variables.

```
from sys import argv; open(argv[2],'w').write(open(argv[1]).read())
```

Comment: that's not a line of code...this is cheating ;) and any serious  manual should not encourage this pratice..

Answer (score 3):

Two things that you need to know:

1) You can include multiple python statements on the same line by separating them with semicolons

2) You don't need to move the command line parameters into separate variables in order to use them.

Comment: I really like this answer best. It explains with enough detail to solve the problem without actually giving it away. Since the person asking the question is trying to learn, better to give them the tools rather than do it for them.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to echo the other posters here who point out that these one-liners are hideous.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the multiple `__import__`of @katrielalex you could do:

`(lambda a:open(a[2],"w").write(open(a[1]).read()))(__import__('sys').argv)`

It's shorter, but it's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the second line and reference `argv` directly in the third. To combine the remaining lines, you could use a semicolon. It's kind of cheating, but I don't see any better solution as you must import sys.

```
from sys import argv; open(argv[2],'w').write(open(argv[1]).read())
```

Comment: why do you consider it cheating? Apparently the only rule is "make it one line". The rule isn't "make it one expression".

Comment: Because that would make it a silly riddle. It makes much more sense the riddler asked for one statement like in the answer provided by @katrielalex

Comment: @Bryan ok, but the manual is supposed to teach python, not bad python

Comment: There's no good without bad. You have to know what's wrong too for a full understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning this too.

```
from_file, to_file = raw_input("copy from: "), raw_input("copy to: ")

open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import sys

open(sys.argv[3], 'w').write(open(sys.argv[2]).read())
```

is probably the best you can do.

Comment: -1 because a) it doesn't reduce the problem to a single line, and b) your answer implies it can't be done, which is false.

Comment: OK @Bryan let the questioner think that `from sys import argv; open(argv[2],'w').write(open(argv[1]).read())` is good python semantics.

Comment: I don't think the issue is about good semantics. This isn't a person saying "I want to reduce my line count", it was "I'm working through a problem set and one problem is, make these three lines into one". I'll agree it's bad practice but that's beside the point. Sometimes people need to see how to do something the wrong way so they'll experience exactly why it is wrong.